# Set debugger from at&t to intel

Tags: intel, c

I want to set my assembly debugger from at&t to intel in gcc. I'm currently on ubuntu 18.0. How can i do this?

Comment: Hi Vivek and welcome to askubuntu! I think what you mean is the different syntax fo A&T and Intel. You have to specifiy in your post the program you would like to  change the syntax. masm, yasm, gcc have option which provide such options. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347909/can-i-use-intel-syntax-of-x86-assembly-with-gcc

Comment: for gcc i have to change..

Answer (score 2):

## GCC assembler output in intel syntax

Assuming you use gcc you have a flag called **-masm=dialect**

From the manual of gcc:

```
-masm=dialect
       Output assembly instructions using selected dialect.  Also
       affects which dialect is used for basic "asm" and extended "asm".
       Supported choices (in dialect order) are att or intel. The
       default is att. Darwin does not support intel.
```

To get a intel syntax you have to compile with

```
gcc -S -masm=intel adder.c
```

---

Here I have a small example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = atoi(argv[1]), b = atoi(argv[2]);
    int sum=0;

    sum = a+b;
    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, sum);

    return 0;
 }
```

Save this as adder.c and compile it

```
gcc adder.c -o adder
```

and test the program with

```
./adder 1 4
```

The output should be

```
1 + 4 = 5
```

Now make an intel asm file with

```
gcc -S  -masm=intel adder.c
```

Here the first lines of adder.s

```
.file   "adder.c"
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .text
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
     .string    "%d + %d = %d\n"
     .text
     .globl main
     .type  main, @function
main:
.LFB5:
    .cfi_startproc
    push    rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    mov rbp, rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    sub rsp, 32
    mov DWORD PTR -20[rbp], edi
    mov QWORD PTR -32[rbp], rsi
    mov rax, QWORD PTR -32[rbp]
    add rax, 8
    mov rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
```

---

## Using intel syntax in GDB

Now compile the last example with debug option:

```
gcc -g adder.c -o adder
```

Open gnu debugger

```
gdb -q --args ./adder 3 5
```

and set the **flavor**

```
set disassembly-flavor intel
```

set a break at main

```
b main
```

and run the program

```
r
```

If you type now

```
disassemble
```

you will get the code in intel style:

```
(gdb) disassemble 
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x000055555555468a <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x000055555555468b <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x000055555555468e <+4>:     sub    rsp,0x20
   0x0000555555554692 <+8>:     mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14],edi
   0x0000555555554695 <+11>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20],rsi
=> 0x0000555555554699 <+15>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20]
   0x000055555555469d <+19>:    add    rax,0x8
   0x00005555555546a1 <+23>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rax]
```

To set your flavor back you have to change it back to at&t style:

```
set disassembly-flavor att
```

- To permanently get intel syntax in your gdb, type the following in your shell:

  ```
  echo "set disassembly-flavor intel" >> ~/.gdbinit
  ```

This will set the property to your `.gdbinit` file. To change simply edit this file.

Comment: can you tell me simple command to do it bcz i have to use gdb.

Comment: @vivek: i added gdb case in my post